# how to deploying the war into (Apache + Glassfish)

Tags: apache, glassfish, mod-jk

I gonna use Glassfish behind the Apache Http Server, my question is how should I deploy my war into these servers? deploy on Apache? or seprate the contents of war to static and servlets/JPS(java) and deploy statics on Apache and other dynamic java into Glassfish?

RGDS